# コードチェックツールの Goodcheck と Phinder の違いはなんですか？

Tags: php, github

Sider というコードレビュー自動ツールをインストールしたのですが、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Sider cannot find the required configuration file(s): phinder.yml.
Please set up Phinder by following the instructions, or you can disable it in the repository settings.

Sider cannot find the required configuration file goodcheck.yml.
Please set up Goodcheck by following the instructions, or you can disable it in the repository settings.
```

この２つは定石から外れたコードを指摘するものではなく、自分で取り決めたコーディングルールに反してないのかをチェックするツールですよね？

GoodCheck と Phinder の違いはなんでしょうか？
どちらか一方でいいような気がするのですが・・・

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

以下のリンク先に簡単な説明が記載されています。

PHP 向けが「Phinder」、言語を限定せずに利用できるのが「Goodcheck」だと私は理解しました。
不要な機能についてはエラー (ワーニング？) に出ている通り、リポジトリの設定にて無効にすればよいのではないでしょうか。
(詳細な使い方に関しては私も把握していないので、まずマニュアル等を参照してみてください)

[プロダクト | Sider](https://sider.review/ja/features)

> #### 最適なツールを選択しましょう
>
> 開発プロジェクトにて利用しているプログラミング言語に応じて、Querly、Phinder、JavaSee、TyScanの中から適切なツールを選びましょう。
>   (中略)
>   Goodcheckは正規表現に基づいたパターンでルールを記述します。プログラミング言語を限定せずに、テキストファイルであればどのようなファイルでも検査することができます。